# Extract numbers from a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

I have made a `JFormattedTextField` that is formatted to only take numbers:

```
Number num;
JFormattedTextField Length =  new JFormattedTextField(num);
```

Now I want to get the number out of that and multiply it by `23`. I know you can do:

```
String LengthStr = Length.getText();
int LengthInt = Integer.parseInt(LengthStr);
int Total = LengthInt*23;
```

But Isn't there an easier way? I've tried:

```
int LengthInt = Length.getText();
int Total = LengthInt * 23;
```

because it should be a number already.

The above didn't work because it says

`Required: int Found: String`

What I 'm asking for is that  if the `JFormattedTextField` is formatted to be an `int`, then surely I can do something like

```
int LengthInt = Length.getInt();
int Total = LengthInt *23;
```

Comment: What? The second one didn't because it says `Required: int Found: String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The line: `int LengthInt = Length.getText();` tries to put a String Object (`Length.getText()`) into an primitive tipe (`int`).

There is no implicit conversion from String to integer in Java, because a String can contain anything (like "abc", for example) that is not directly convertible to a number.

Also, the first two lines should be changed to this: `JFormattedTextField Length =  new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());` Instantiate the JFormattedTextField with the NumberFormat instead of Number.

Comment: So is there no other way to do this?

Comment: Make it smaller by doing it all in one line: int LengthInt = Integer.parseInt(Length.getText());